# Account creation in private testnet vs mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, accounts, testnets

When we setup geth private testnet, we define one genesis file. Suppose after mining 100 blocks I want to create one more account. In this case I will update the `alloc` key of genesis file with new account address. When I will restart the geth node, a new blockchain will be started because genesis file has been changed. 
So my question is "What happened when someone create the new account on livenet (mainnet)." Because a new blockchain is not started there. Correct me if I am wrong in any concept. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accounts in the genesis file are a initialization to define the blockchain parameters, it is not the way used to create accounts ( in genesis file you define some account with some balances in a private chaine just to help you starting sending/receiving ethers). you could use a genesis file without any account.

to create a new account you use the ethereum's clients eth,geth..

for example : `geth account new` this has no relation with the genesis file.

read about account managment : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Just one more question. Can Account created using personal.newAccount() be updated using 'geth account update'?

Comment: yes just add the account addresse